# insert font tag inside all paragraph tag or wrap text inside paragraph tag with font tag (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

I've a string variable with it value as follows. Just some html content.

```
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simpl...</p> 
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the in...</p> 
<p>Lorem Ipsum i...</p> <p>Lorem Ipygutyu...</p> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simtyu...</p>
```

I have to wrap text inside all the paragraph tags with a font tag like this

How can I achive this. The result should be like this

```
<p><font face="Arial">Lorem Ipsum idfg dfgs simpl...</font></p> 
<p><font face="Arial">Lorem Ipsum is simdfg pl...</font></p> 
<p><font face="Arial">Lorem Ipsum ert retreis simpl...</font></p> <p><font face="Arial">Lorem Ipsuertrem is simpl...</font></p> <p><font face="Arial">Lorem Ipsumfghfgh is simpl...</font></p>
```

Comment: Would string `Replace` help you in this case? Seems straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourtext = yourtext.Replace("<p>", "<p><font face=""Arial"">").Replace("</p>", "</font></p>")
```

Comment: Friend, actually I missed something in the description which is it wont be just <p> tag only and some texts inside. There will be span tags maybe inside the P tag and sometimes there will be inline styles for the <P> tag. So we cant just replace <P> tag. Actually I achieved this using JQUERY (Wrap and Unwrap method)